# <HtmlContent> does not exist in the current Context

Tags: c#, asp.net, class, stored-procedures

here comes an Error that HtmlContent does not exist in the current context. Can anybody help me understand why VisualStudio is giving this error?

```
  private void WriteEmployeesList()
    {
        StringBuilder htmlStr = new StringBuilder("");
        int numEmployees = db.CountEmployees();
        htmlStr.Append("<br />Total employees: <b>");
        htmlStr.Append(numEmployees.ToString());
        htmlStr.Append("</b><br /><br />");
        List<EmployeeDetails> employees = db.GetEmployees();
        foreach (EmployeeDetails emp in employees)
        {
            htmlStr.Append("<li>");
            htmlStr.Append(emp.EmployeeID);
            htmlStr.Append(" ");
            htmlStr.Append(emp.TitleOfCourtesy);
            htmlStr.Append(" <b>");
            htmlStr.Append(emp.FirstName);
            htmlStr.Append("</b>, ");
            htmlStr.Append(emp.LastName);
            htmlStr.Append("</li>");
        }
        htmlStr.Append("<br />");
        HtmlContext.Text += htmlStr.ToString();
    }

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            WriteEmployeesList();
            // The ID value is simply set to 0, because it's generated by the
            // database server and filled in automatically when you call
            // InsertEmployee().
            int empID = db.InsertEmployee(new EmployeeDetails(0, "Mr.", "Bellinaso", "Marco"));

            HtmlContent.Text += "<br />Inserted 1 employee.<br />";
            WriteEmployeesList();
            db.DeleteEmployee(empID);
            HtmlContent.Text += "<br />Deleted 1 employee.<br />";
            WriteEmployeesList();
        }


<asp:Content ID="HeaderContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent">
    <asp:Literal ID="Literal1" runat="server" Text="HtmlContent"></asp:Literal>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
    <h2>
        Welcome to ASP.NET!
    </h2>
    <p>
        To learn more about ASP.NET visit <a href="http://www.asp.net" title="ASP.NET Website">
            www.asp.net</a>.
    </p>
    <p>
        You can also find <a href="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=152368&amp;clcid=0x409"
            title="MSDN ASP.NET Docs">documentation on ASP.NET at MSDN</a>.
    </p>
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be better if you have posted the code portion that is actually causing error?

Comment: Please post the full exception details, including stack trace

Comment: Show the ASPX or C# code that creates the control, and on what line is the error occurring, please?

Comment: Could you please, tell the line number showing error,

Comment: @abdul 27,55, 30 are the line numbers

Comment: You need `<ul>` tags wrapping your foreach.

Answer (score 2):

htmlContent must be declared with this name in the .aspx page as a label or div or some other container. Then you will be able to populate and the code will work as far as I can see.
htmlContent is not a key word or a method or an object. It is just the name of a html element on the .aspx side.
Kind regards,
Ola Balstad

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess but try including `InitializeComponent();` in your page_load function. It needs to appear before anything else so put it on the first line.

Alternatively, check your code behind file name and Inherits property on the @Page directive and make sure they both match.